# Nashorn : synchronized methods and blocks

Tags: nashorn

Straightforward question : how to mark methods and blocks of code as synchronized in js scripts. Also a way to implement the volatile keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Javascript (Browser and Node.js) run single threaded there is no need to mark methods as synchronized. afaik Nashorn is not yet multithreaded (see https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/nashorn_multi_threading_and_mt)

Comment: Ive read that article in the past, indeed implementing web workers is plausible solution. Was expecting more suggestions due to lack of resources on nashorn, but anyway ill accept ur answer. Ty again

Comment: I am sorry not give you a better (expected) answer. But due to the fact that JS was invented as a singlethreaded language and node.js using exactly this as the USP I dont see how you will escape this. At least as long you stay on JS (the lang). Maybe you can writer your own macros via sweet.js?

Comment: Yea no way to escape it indeed hhh

Comment: Im letting you know, that ive hacked a lot into the java source, and discovered this new Lock interface that helps implement the synchronized mechanism without need of synchronized keyword.

Answer (score 1):

load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js")

// the above defines "sync" builtin function 
// like Rhino shell ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Shell )
// does

var func = sync(function() {
});

// lock on 'this'

func();